# Visualize an n-row and n-column matrix

Tags: python, visualisation, similarity

I have a 275 rows and a 275 columns matrix,the value in the matrix is between 0.99 and 1.Each value is 6 digits after the decimal point,such as 0.993428,0.999657.It can be understood that this is a similarity matrix,I want to visualize this matrix to have an intuitive effect.Part of the data is as follows.

> [image]

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org)'s [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(ar)
```